# Vue modal with a router

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vue. I am building a simple app that will list all countries and when you click on a particular country it shows you more details about the country. Idea is to open `country details` in a modal.

I'm stuck with displaying that modal. The modal opens, but in the background. It also opens a detail page.

`CountryDetail.vue`:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'country-detail',
  props: [ 'isDarkTheme' ],
  data () {
    return {
      pending: false,
      error: null,
      countryInfo: null,
      alpha3Code: [],
      alpha3CodetoString: [],
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.pending = true;
    axios
      .get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${this.$route.params.country}?fullText=true`)
      .then((response) => {
        (this.countryInfo = response.data)
        this.alpha3CodetoString = this.alpha3Code.join(';');
      })
      .catch(error => (this.error = error ))
      .finally( () => { this.pending = false });
  },
  filters: {
    formatNumbers (value) {
      return `${value.toLocaleString()}`
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
<modal v-model="show">
        <div class="modal-mask" :class="{ darkTheme : isDarkTheme }" name="modal">
          <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div  class="modal-container">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <slot name="header">
                   <h1 v-if="error !== null">Sorry, an error has occurred {{error}}</h1>
                  <div class="loaderFlex"><div v-if="pending" class="loader"></div></div>
                </slot>
              </div>

              <div v-for="country in countryInfo" class="countryTile modal-body" v-bind:key="country.id">
                <slot name="body">
                    <img v-bind:src="country.flag" alt="Country Flag" class="flag">
                  <div class="country-details">
                        <h1>{{country.name}}</h1>
                        <div class="listDiv">
                        <ul>      
                            <li><span>Population:</span> {{country.population | formatNumbers }}</li>
                            <li><span>Capital:</span> {{country.capital}}</li>
                            <li><span>Iso:</span> {{country.alpha3Code}}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>   
                            <li><span>Currencies:</span> {{country.currencies['0'].name}}</li>
                            <li><span>Languages:</span> 
                            <span 
                                v-for="(language, index) in country.languages" 
                                v-bind:key="index" 
                                class="languages">
                                {{language.name}}<span v-if="index + 1 < country.languages.length">, </span>
                            </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </slot>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <slot name="footer">
                <a @click="$router.go(-1)" class="backBtn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left" />Go Back</a>
                </slot>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </modal>
</template>
```

`Home.vue`:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'home',
  props: [ 'isDarkTheme' ],
  data () {
    return {
      pending: false,
      error: null,
      countryInfo: null,
      search: '',   
      darkMode: false,
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.pending = true;
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => (this.countryInfo = response.data))
      .catch(error => (this.error = error ))
      .finally( () => { this.pending = false });
  },
 
  filters: {
    formatNumbers (value) {
      return `${value.toLocaleString()}`
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredCountries: function () {
      return this.countryInfo.filter((country) => {
        if (this.region === '' ) {
          return country.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
        } else if (this.search !== '') {
          return country.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
        } else {
          return ('blbla');
        }
      })
    }
  }, 
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="home" :class="{ darkTheme : isDarkTheme }">
    <div class="searchBar">
      <div class="searchContainer">
        <i class="fas fa-search searchIcon"></i>
        <input 
          class="searchInput" 
          type="text" 
          v-model="search"
          aria-label="Search for a country..."
          placeholder="Search for a country..."
        />
        <ul class="searchResults"></ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <h1 v-if="error !== null">Sorry, an error has occurred {{error}}</h1> 
    <div class="loaderFlex"><div v-if="pending" class="loader"></div></div>

    <div v-if="countryInfo" class="tileGrid" @click="showModal = true">
      <div v-for="country in filteredCountries" class="countryTile" v-bind:key="country.id">
        <router-link 
          :to="{ name: 'country-detail', params: {country: country.name }}" 
          class="linkTile"
        >
          <img v-bind:src="country.flag" alt="Country Flag" class="flag">
          <div class="text">
            <h1>{{ country.name }}</h1>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router-link will always redirect you to another page, because its basically `<a href="...">` [see here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link). You don't need router if you just want to show the detail on a modal, you could just add the modal component inside the **Home.vue** component, then bind the modal and the `countryName` with props, then pass them in when clicking a button.

`Home.vue`:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <button @click="showDetail">
   Show Detail
  </button>

  <CountryDetail :countryName="countryName" :showModal="showModal"/>
 <div>
</template>

<script>
 import CountryDetail from './CountryDetail.vue'

 export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: { CountryDetail },
  data: () => ({
   countryName: '',
   showModal: false,
  }),
  methods: {
   showDetail() {
    this.showModal = true;
   },
  },
 }
</script>
```

And instead of making request on `mounted`, you could use `watch` to do something like watching for the `showModal` prop, and make request everytime it has a truthy value. Like this:

`CountryDetail.vue`:

```
<template>
 <modal v-model="showModal">
  <!-- modal content -->
 </modal>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   name: 'CountryDetail',
   props: ['countryName', 'showModal'],
   watch: {
     'showModal': {
       deep: true,
       handler(val) {
         if (val && this.countryName !== '') {
           // Make request
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```